# ipywidgets widgets.IntRangeSlider text size

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

I'm doing some interactive plotting in jupyter notebook using `widgets.IntRangeSlider`, but text doesn't appear fully visible, how to set size of text area?

Here is a code sample:

```
interactive_plot = interactive(plot_chart,
                                 val=widgets.IntRangeSlider(value=[0, 300], min=0, max=300, step=10,
                                                           description='Платеж, тыс. руб.',
                                                           continuous_update=False
                                                           )
                              )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer [here](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#Description).

Example:

```
style = {'description_width': 'initial'}
IntSlider(description='A too long description', style=style)
```